# Issues with the scaling of the chat logo on the beta chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, design

This is a somewhat minor design issue:

Currently, across all SE site chatrooms there is an inline style `max-width` on the footer logo (bottom right-hand side of each chatroom) that scales the logo if it's width is *greater than* `150px` (there's also a `max-height` attribute set in the css for limiting the height).

This is very noticeable on beta sites with very long names such as "[Chinese Language and Usage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1984/)." Certain graduated sites with longer logos, like "[English Language Usage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog)," are affected as well.

[image: Exhibit A] [image: Exhibit 1] (actual size)

I'd also like to make note that the font color of the main site name portion on the chatroom footer logos don't contrast very well against the dark-blue colored background (with the diagonal scanlines), when compared to the lighter font color of the "beta" text in the logo.

[image: Another Exhibit] (actual size)

Would it be possible to use a better contrasting color for the site name on the beta chatroom footer logo?

Would it be possible to change the `max-width` to something like `250px` to improve readability of the logo?